# Robust way to write text to a buffer

Tags: buffers

What would be a robust way to write to a buffer.  The buffer might not exist, and there might be a need to specify the buffer rather than assuming that one is writing in the current buffer (although one can make a buffer current momentarily).

For instance, is it better to use

```
(print "something" xbuff)
```

over

```
(with-current-buffer xbuff
  (insert "something"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` is always robust. There is always at least one buffer, and there is always a current buffer for it to insert into. It may not be the buffer that you want though, so sometimes you will want to use `with-current-buffer` or similar functions to change what buffer you are working with. There’s no universal way of doing this; every situation is unique.

That said, it is common to write one function that inserts things into the current buffer, and to call that function from code that arranges for the correct buffer to be made current. For example, when you use `C-x C-b` to view the buffer list, the function `list-buffers-noselect` uses `with-current-buffer` to make the `*Buffer List*` buffer current, and then it calls `tabulated-list-print` to actually print out the buffer list. `tabulated-list-print` does not try to ensure that the correct buffer is selected; it requires that it’s caller has already done that.

Comment: Your answer made me wonder what happens when you call `(mapc #'kill-buffer (buffer-list))`. ;-)

Comment: Try it and find out :D